# Roblox Studio My script only works one time

Tags: lua, roblox

I made a gun shop website. When I try to buy a gun the first time it works but, when I delete the gun from my inventory and try again it wont work.

Please Help.

```
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")

local Vendedor = script.Parent
local ClickDetector = game.Workspace.Lojadearmas.Vendedor.ClickDetector

local Glock = ServerStorage:WaitForChild("G17"):Clone()

ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    print(player.name)
    local Player = player
    local Gui = player.PlayerGui.LojaArmas
    Gui.Frame.Visible = true
    Gui.Frame2.Visible = true
    Gui.Glock.Visible = true
    Gui.Fechar.Visible = true
    Gui.Loja.Visible = true
    
    Gui.Fechar.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        Gui.Frame.Visible = false
        Gui.Frame2.Visible = false
        Gui.Glock.Visible = false
        Gui.Fechar.Visible = false
        Gui.Loja.Visible = false
        print(Player)
    end)
    
    Gui.Glock.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        if Player.leaderstats.Reais.Value >= 1000 then
        Glock.Parent = Player.Backpack
        print(Player.leaderstats.Reais.Value)
        Player.leaderstats.Reais.Value = Player.leaderstats.Reais.Value - 1000
        end 
    end)
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are cloning it once when you referenced the variable Glock. Try this:

```lua
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")

local Vendedor = script.Parent
local ClickDetector = game.Workspace.Lojadearmas.Vendedor.ClickDetector

local Glock = ServerStorage:WaitForChild("G17")

ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    print(player.name)
    local Player = player
    local Gui = player.PlayerGui.LojaArmas
    Gui.Frame.Visible = true
    Gui.Frame2.Visible = true
    Gui.Glock.Visible = true
    Gui.Fechar.Visible = true
    Gui.Loja.Visible = true
    
    Gui.Fechar.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        Gui.Frame.Visible = false
        Gui.Frame2.Visible = false
        Gui.Glock.Visible = false
        Gui.Fechar.Visible = false
        Gui.Loja.Visible = false
        print(Player)
    end)
    
    Gui.Glock.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        if Player.leaderstats.Reais.Value >= 1000 then
        Glock:Clone().Parent = Player.Backpack
        print(Player.leaderstats.Reais.Value)
        Player.leaderstats.Reais.Value = Player.leaderstats.Reais.Value - 1000
        end 
    end)
end)
```

Let me know if you require any further assistance.